# Append data from an array to a char variable in C

Tags: c

i have a program that i'm writing, and i need to read in a configuration file. if you can't tell by the way it's written it is a placeholder for another program, it opens the second program in its memory space. I have the readline function all set up, but my "main" operation will only support a variable for arguments (unless im incorrect), like this: "arg1 arg2 arg3..." I have seen things on the net like 'strcat' and others, but since im not so versed in C these seem to only add a single character. my needed solution would be:

```
char args[ 10 ];
FILE *fp=fopen("file.cfg","r");

void readLine(FILE* file, char* line, int limit)
{
    int i;
    int read;

    read = fread(line, sizeof(char), limit, file);
    line[read] = '\0';

    for(i = 0; i <= read;i++)
    {
        if('\0' == line[i] || '\n' == line[i] || '\r' == line[i])
        {
            line[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }

    if(i != read)
    {
        fseek(file, i - read + 1, SEEK_CUR);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    _spawnl( P_OVERLAY, "prog1.exe", "prog1.exe", args, NULL );
    return 0;
}
```

the 'args' variable in 'int main(void)' would need to be the one that is = line[i].
unless a complete rewrite would be nessecary.

Also b4 you flame me, i dont want a loop in main, because this program just calls another, then dies. A loop might make it call an infinite number of the same program, and... well that would be bad. thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not C++ code, this is C. Removing tag.

Comment: Perhaps `args` should be an array of pointer-to-char, e.g. `char *args[10]`. I can't say for sure without seeing the docs for `_spawnl`.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa273352(v=vs.60).aspx <- here. Also not looking for portability

Comment: So that says `int _spawnl( int mode, const char *cmdname, const char *arg0, const char *arg1, ... const char *argn, NULL );` which means that after you fill an array of pointer-to-char, you need to call the function like this `_spawnl( P_OVERLAY, args[0], args[0], args[1], args[2], NULL )`. Note that args[0] would be "prog1.exe", and the remaining args come from the file.

Comment: Yes that is the functionality im looking for, but im at a loss at how to do it

Comment: @Spilt_Blood Maybe there's a function `_spawnv` that takes a single array of arguments instead of spreading them out.

Comment: I was right, there is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa273357(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: i never got that to work, but i can try again

Comment: Use `_execv` to replace the program in the current process instead of spawning a new process.

Comment: It's not necessary to write your own readline function, fgets or getline will do.

Comment: @Barmar the file path has spaces in it... i get an error about conversion   main.cpp:57:129: error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'const char* const*' for argument '2' to 'intptr_t _execv(const char*, const char* const*)'

Comment: If you want to be able to pass multiple arguments, it should be `char *args[10]`, not `char args[10]`. And your code that parses the line needs to split it into separate strings for each argument. Take a look at `strtok()` to simplify this.

Comment: @Barmar for some reason _execv does not  call the .exe to be executed... it just silently quits

Comment: You must be calling it incorrectly.

Comment: _execv( "prog1.exe", args );   but as i said b4 the path has a space in it. is this causing the issue

Comment: A char variable can only ever hold one character (not zero, not two or more). Good thing `args` isn't a char variable; it's an *array* of chars.